# Reactjs - js inside html elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my project, I have a button which I want to disable using state.

```
<Button 
    color='success' 
    onClick={this.changeForm}
    block
    disabled
    >
    LOGIN
</Button>
```

I am using [Reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/buttons/). I have a `flag` value set in the `state`. I want to disable the button if `flag` is set to `TRUE`. So, I came up with this code:

```
<Button 
    color='success' 
    onClick={this.changeForm}
    block
    {this.state.flag && 'disabled'}
    >
    LOGIN
</Button>
```

I am getting `Syntax Error`. I understand that that's a not proper syntax so how can I achieve the functionality that I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`disabled` is a prop of `Button`. Thus:

```
<Button 
    color='success' 
    onClick={this.changeForm}
    disabled={this.state.flag}
    >
    LOGIN
</Button>
```

Comment: Absolutely not stupid. You don’t know until you know ;)